# How to inject blazor session storage in a C# class

Tags: c#-4.0, blazor-server-side, session-storage

I want to inject the Blazor sessionStorage in a class like the code below.

```
    [Inject]
    Blazored.SessionStorage.ISessionStorageService _sessionStorage
```

A lot of examples online show or place this in the Html file.

Is there a way to inject this in a C# class? I tried with the above code and it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public partial class MyComponent
{
   [Inject] Blazored.SessionStorage.ISessionStorageService _sessionStorage {get; set;}
...
}
```